# UISearchDisplayController to active state without the dimmed tableView

Tags: ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am implementing a UISearchDisplayController.
As the controller becomes active I load up the tableView with previous search terms, this is done so the user can easily tap the searchField, set the view in the search state - ***But*** if one of the users last 4-5 search terms is the one they are looking for they can just select it from the tableView.

The problem is that until anything is entered into the searchField then tableView remains "dimmed".

I have not been able so get around this, could someone please help figure it out. I have found no mention of the dimming in the UISearchDisplayController Class documentation or in the delegate documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get any answer i am having the same problem... Thanks

Comment: I ended up writing my own. the SearchDisplayController is not meant to be customized.

Comment: Thanks RickiG... I have used UIsearchedBar and managed things by my own ...

Answer (score 0):

You could try the horrible hack that's the selected answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473579/uisearchdisplaydelegate-how-to-remove-this-opaque-view).

Answer (score 0):

Starting from iOS8 you can use the dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation
 Property

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchController/dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation