# UISearchDisplayDelegate how to remove this opaque view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

how can i programmatically show/hide this opaque view from **UISearchDisplayController**?

[image]

Probably in `searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch` or `searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch` i need to set something... but what?

thanks.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527927/uisearchdisplaycontroller-without-dimming

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Temporary solved** using `UIKeyboardWillAppearNotification`.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

OpaqueView is an **UIControl** with alpha = 0.8.

```
- (void) keyboardWillShow {
  for( UIView *subview in self.view.subviews ) {
   if( [subview isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]] ) {
      UIControl *v = (UIControl*)subview;
      if (v.alpha < 1) {
        v.hidden = YES;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I used this **ORRIBLE way to temporary fix** problem.... any other idea **will be appreciated**!

thanks.

Comment: Horrible, but still the best answer I've found.

Answer (score 2):

**Code given by elpsk is current but will not work in *iOS7 and above***

**Code working in both iOS6 and iOS7 is as below**

- add below notification in viewDidLoad

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

Write below function

```
- (void) keyboardWillShow {
      for( UIView *subview in self.view.subviews ) {
       if([subview  isMemberOfClass:[UIControl class]] ||
         ([[[subview  class] description] isEqualToString:@"UISearchDisplayControllerContainerView"])) {
          UIControl *v = (UIControl*)subview;
          if (v.alpha < 1) {
            v.hidden = YES;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**NOTE :** Code just have one extra condition as in iOS7 UIControl class become UISearchDisplayControllerContainerView,

Comment: There appears to be no need for checking the alpha, especially since a) you already check for it's type (here I would suggest to use the classname) and b) the alpha of this view is actually 1.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers where not working for me. This one works for me on iOS7 and iOS8.

```
for( UIView *subview in self.view.subviews ) {
    if([subview  isMemberOfClass:[UIControl class]] ||
       ([[[subview  class] description] isEqualToString:@"UISearchDisplayControllerContainerView"])) {
        for(UIView *subView2 in subview.subviews)
        {
            for(UIView *subView3 in subView2.subviews)
            {
                if (subView3.alpha < 1) {
                    subView3.hidden = YES;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't need support for iOS7 please don't use the searchDisplayController anymore because its deprecated. For iOS8 use the UISearchController and the dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation
 Property

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchController/dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm...quick answer. Not pretty but surely works

```
    #pragma mark UISearchBarDelegate

// Displays a view to simulate the lose of focus
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

  searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
  searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

  UIButton *view1 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
  view1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, MAX(480, self.tableView.contentSize.height));
  view1.alpha = 0.6;
  view1.tag = 2000;
  view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
  [view1  addTarget:self
             action:@selector(removeView)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:NO];

  [self.tableView addSubview:view1];
  [view1 release];
}

/**
 *  Pop the view and the keyboard
 */
- (void)removeView {
  UIView *v = [self.tableView viewWithTag:2000];
  v.hidden = YES;
  [v removeFromSuperview];
  [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:YES];
  [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

That view is showed when you're writing, so I guess you should use it at searchBarTextDidBeginEditing. If I'm wrong, use it when you start searching or whatever.