# UISearchDisplayController change dimmed view frame

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

In my iPad app I have an UITableView. Table's frame size is less than screen size, so to make search functionality look nice I have to adjust searchResultTableView's frame to fit my TableView. I'm doing it in my UISearchDisplayDelegate's  -searchDisplayController:willShowSearchResultsTableView: method.

Everything works fine except dimming view. When I'm starting search dimming view's width is equal to screen width:

[image: dimming view takes whole screen]

When I start entering search string or clear textfield my searchResultsTableView resizes properly and everything works as it should:

[image: search results tableview is resizes properly]

[image: dimming view is resized as well]

I tried to change searchResultsTableView frame inside -searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch: method using this line

```
controller.searchResultsTableView.frame = myFrame;
```

but it doesn't work as well. Any suggestions besides implementing my own search display controller?

Comment: Solved!

Refer to this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473579/uisearchdisplaydelegate-how-to-remove-this-opaque-view

Answer (score 1):

I also needed to change the frame of the dimming view but for a different reason. In my case I created a UISearchDisplayController and UISearchBar programmatically in a regular UIViewController not a UITableViewController. I was also using MFSideMenu which added to the complexity of the problem. What ended up happening was the dimming view was in the correct position initially but the next time the search was cleared the dimming view shifted leftwards and upwards by exactly half of it's size. Given the UISearchDisplayController you can find the dimming view like so.

```
for(UIView * v in controller.searchContentsController.view.subviews)
{
    if([v isMemberOfClass:[UIControl class]])
    {
        v.frame = newFrame; //This frame should account for the UISearchBar
    }
}
```

To handle for the initial incorrect frame you should change it in this delegate method:

```
- (void) searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
```

To handle for an incorrect frame on any subsequent clears you should change it in this delegate method:

```
- (void) searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didHideSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;
```

Note: this solution runs through the subviews of the searchContentsController which is one of the reasons I used isMemberOfClass instead of isKindOfClass (UIButton is a subclass of UIControl). Further discrimination would be required if you added a UIControl instance into your view (you could use tags to help determine which ones are yours).